# What is the fuse with a label of T on it?

Tags: fuses, playstation-5

I'm working on a Playstation 5 and found that I needed to change this fuse. I'm not sure which this one is as there are so many types of tiny fuses out there. What does this T stand for? How should I measure it to find how to source this on digikey or mouser?

[image]

Comment: Could you please put a cleaned one's photo?

Comment: please review a photo after you capture it ... keep taking pictures until you have a good one

Comment: Also, put another photo showing the surrounding components. It's not clear if F7002 is the said component's designator.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not a fuse. More likely it's a ferrite bead like these: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.koaspeer.com/products/leaded-resistors/general-purpose-leaded/czp/).

> *How should I measure it to find how to source this on digikey or
> mouser?*

Given that it's likely not to be a fuse and, given that it's more likely to be a ferrite bead, you can verify it's working by measuring the resistance.

Whether it's a fuse or a ferrite bead, expect to see a fraction of an ohm to a few ohms. You can't really determine anything by measuring a fuse and, unfortunately, its the same story with a ferrite bead.

Comment: I've never seen ferrite beads with a 'T' printed on them. Also not 0R link resistors. But 5A SMD fuses with marking 'T', yes.

Answer (score 1):

F7001 is a fuse, I believe it is on the output of a 5 V switching regulator. The 'T' marking may indicate a 5 A fuse, you would probably need to check a schematic to be sure.

There are a number of fuses all prominently marked on the board with numbers in the Fxxx format. F7002 is the one that seems to blow the most often.

You can test it with an ohmmeter or continuity tester (with the unit's power disconnected of course). With power on it should show around 5 V on either side of it.

Comment: Not all manufacturers use "T" for 5 Amps. Littlefuse does, Bourns doesn't, for example. Also it's not clear if F7002 is the aforementioned component's designator. There's another designator partly visible above the component.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The fuse shown is F7001. There is no other designator above it, those are pads for a component that's not placed. I just mentioned F7002 as an example of another fuse with the same identifier format. Qualified the part about the fuse value.

Comment: @RohatKılıç by searching found some pictures of the PCB from two different sides. F7001 shown on one [side](http://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/531442ffe4b03cbb511321a9/1630800671941-2091PYI6F1POY3A1GSM7/PBuWZ1XpeOnKIkIe.jpeg). F7002 shown on a partial picture of the other [side](https://advancedrepair.co.uk/ps5-motherboard-f7002-circuit-repair-1831-p.asp). No experience in trying to repair; just curious.

Comment: Which component is likely to have failed to cause the fuse to blow?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Who knows. It may not have been an on board component,  that fuse might feed some of the ports so the cause of it blowing (although we haven't actually determined that it's blown yet) could be external.